# Translations only work with underscore lang code (i.e.: es_ES) in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, internationalization

I'm developing a site with Symfony2 v.2.5.0-dev and i'm trying to internationalize it.

It works fine in english `(mysite.com/en/)` and french `(mysite.com/fr/)` but for catalan and spanish only works with URLs like `mysite.com/ca_ES/` and `mysite.com/es_ES/` but I need to use the short language codes: `ca` and `es`.

The default language is Catalan.

I've created 4 files in `src/MyProject/MyBundle/Resources/translations` with name:

- messages.ca.yml
- messages.es.yml
- messages.en.yml
- messages.fr.yml

And enabled the translator:

```
#app/config/config.yml
framework:
    translator:      { fallback: ca }
    default_locale:  %locale%


#app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
   ...
   locale: ca
```

I'd made before some other projects in Symfony2 v.2.3.x without this problem.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by clearing the Symfony cache.